# AWS S3 ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, knox-amazon-s3-client, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list buckets following the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html).

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client(service_name = 's3',
                  region_name = 'us-east-2',
                  aws_access_key_id='xxxxxx',
                  aws_secret_access_key= 'xxxxx'
                 )

response = s3.list_buckets()

# Output the bucket names
print('Existing buckets:')
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
```

But it turns out with an error, which says

`ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`

I found some similar posts for this error, but I still don't know how to fix mine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please Edit your question to show the permissions associated with at that Access Key.

Comment: **Side-note:** For improved security, it is recommend to _never_ include your security credentials (Access Key, Secret Key) in your actual code. Instead, store them in a configuration file using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command.

Comment: Your access key does not have permission to ListBuckets in our account. Please ask your admin to provide ListBuckets permission

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code and everything worked properly. And you don't have to specify region_name 'cause anyway you will get all buckets. And then I tried to remove permission to s3 from my user and got the same error. I guess you're getting such an error because of your user's policy.  You should attach content of your policy to the question.

Comment: I'm not the root user. That's all I get in the credentials.csv file. Should I ask the root user to get the policy?

Comment: yes. It probably will help